# Edit a JSON file in azure blob storage by react

Tags: reactjs, azure-blob-storage

I have a json file in my container in azure blob storage. I want to edit it using react js. Like if I have something like "name" : "sandy"; I want to be able to change the name using react

Comment: Can you elaborate bit more on your query?

Answer (score 0):

You would simply have to fetch the blob (download) and display it within an editable field to let the user change the contents.

Once ready to save, you would update the blob (upload) in a similar fashion to the updated content. You would want to do validations to ensure the data being uploaded is correct within react code.

You can perform the upload/download using the [Storage JS SDK](https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=41&q=azure%20storage%20js%20sdk&cvid=f7ffea2b64604f0ea3d0deef0cff2db7&aqs=edge.0.0l9j69i11004.3661j0j1&FORM=ANNAB1&PC=LCTS).